# Synchronize Plesk and Git

Tags: git, github, plesk

I have a server running Plesk Onyx Version 17.8.11 and running CentOS 6.10 OS. Also I have the Git extension installed in version .1.5-250. The extension cannot be updated due to Plesk and OS version.

When I want to add a repository hosted on GitHub, it gives an error. The extension asks for the address of the remote site, indicating that the HTTPS and SSH protocols are supported.

When I put the HTTPS address copied from GitHub, the following error is displayed:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/Sollutia/mediavaca.com.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

If I try over SSH and copy the key to GitHub, it says that the generated key is not secure enough. I have tried changing it in the /.ssh folder and adding the rules to the config file so that it connects through port 443:

```
Host github.com
User git
Port 443
```

Once this is done, he spends some time thinking and the error message appears in Plesk:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is there a way to sync the repository with this version of the Git extension? If it is possible, better by the HTTPS protocol.

Thanks!

Comment: `403 Forbidden` just means that you've used the wrong user-name/"password" (GitHub Token, that is) combination with https, so check your user-name and token.`generated key is not secure enough` isn't a specific error message but *probably* indicates that the ssh implementation here is using RSA1 keys with SHA-1 and/or small bitsizes. If the ssh implementation can use ED25519 keys or larger RSA-2 keys, use those.

Comment: The 403 error in HTTPS is because Github detects incorrect login. But with Git 1.5-250 extension for Plesk, I can't specify GitHub user and token. Do you know where I can put the user and the token in the extension?

Comment: I have no idea. That's why my comment is a comment, not an answer: it's just some info you might find useful.